# Height of header view in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, interface-builder

How can I design a header view for my UICollectionView that either grows or shrinks its height based on the content of it? It contains some labels, but the text of the labels are not known in advance.

Comment: Can you show us some screenshot, code or constraint? If you don't have access to header constraint, you can always add `UIView` `view.addSubview` with programmatically constraint.

Answer (score 0):

If your layout is an `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` (or based on it) you can implement the

```
optional func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                     layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                     referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize
```

function on you view controller and return the header size you want.

See here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout_protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout/collectionView:layout:referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:

Comment: But how am I supposed to design my layout in Interface Builder, where the labels have dynamic height and then know what to return from the delegate method you refer to?

Comment: Not everything can and should be done in interface builder. This is one of them.